# Swift Json - get data from API

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview, alamofire

I have a problem when I tried to GET data from a web api. But what i get is nil.
I couldn't get the article list from the api. Any advice?

api doc address: yazar.io/doc/

My NSObject File:

```
import Alamofire
struct YazarIoService {

    // Doc http://yazar.io/doc/        
    private static let baseURL = "http://yazar.io"
    private enum ResourcePath: Printable {

        case Articles
        case StoryUpvote(storyId: Int)
        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .Articles: return "/api/article/feed/1"
            case .StoryUpvote(let id): return "/api/client/favorites/action/"
            }
        }
    }

    static func articleForSection(section: String, page: Int, response: (JSON) -> ()){

        let urlString = baseURL + ResourcePath.Articles.description
        println(urlString)
        let parameters = [
            "page": toString(page)
        ]
        println(parameters)

        Alamofire.request(.GET, baseURL, parameters: parameters).responseJSON{(_, _, data, _) -> Void in
            let articles = JSON(data ?? [])
            response(articles)
        }
    }
```

My table view controller;

```
class articlesTableViewController: UITableViewController, MakaleTableViewCellDelegate {

    let transitionManager = TransitionManager()
    var articles: JSON! = []

    func loadarticles(section: String, page: Int){
        YazarIoService.articleForSection(section, page: page) { (JSON) -> () in
            self.articles = JSON["articles"]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
     }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        loadarticles("", page: 1)
        println(articles[])
    }

    @IBAction func MenuButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("MenuSegue", sender: self)
    }


    @IBAction func LoginbutonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSegue", sender: self)
    }

    //number of rows
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return articles.count //
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MakaleCell") as MakaleTableViewCell //--> cell'in özelliklerine erişmek içim bunu yazdık. Eskiden UITableViewCell'di. Değiştirmezsen cell.title... vs çalışmakz.

        let makale = articles[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureWithMakale(makale)

        cell.delegate = self

        return cell            
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("WebSegue", sender: indexPath) 

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }


    // MARK: MakaleTableViewCellDelegate

    func makaleTableViewCellDidTouchUpvote(cell: MakaleTableViewCell, sender: AnyObject) {
        // TODO: Implement Upvote
    }

    func makaleTableViewCellDidTouchComment(cell: MakaleTableViewCell, sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("CommentsSegue", sender: self)
    }

    // MARK: Misc

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "WebSegue" {  
            let toView = segue.destinationViewController as WebViewController
            let indexPath = sender as NSIndexPath
            let url = articles[indexPath.row]["article_url"].string!
            toView.url = url


            UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)

            toView.transitioningDelegate = transitionManager
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article on how to properly ask a question. You could improve your question a lot by reducing the amount of code to the code that is problematic and by stating what you’ve already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. My Alamofire.request returns nil.
I couldn't find a way to fix it.

Comment: Debug. Try to use  a println just before you send the request, print the URL that you try to access and paste that url in your web browser, do you get any data at all. Check if you get any data. Post the error that you get. Just a few simple tips on how to help yourself get a better answer from the community

Comment: println(urlString) returns correct url: http://yazar.io/api/article/feed/1 -->correct
println(page) returns : 1 -->correct
println(articles[]) returns nil. It seems that i couldnt parse the data correctly

Comment: Could you println your articles in your loadarticles function for me. Just after you set self.articles

Comment: println(self.articles[]) --> null

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? and just to be sure you put the prinln in     
`func loadarticles(section: String, page: Int){
        YazarIoService.articleForSection(section, page: page) { (JSON) -> () in
            self.articles = JSON["articles"]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
     }`

Comment: No console errors. I put println the place you mentioned, after   
self.articles = JSON["articles"]

Comment: Try parsing as a NSDictionary<String,AnyObject> Than test if you can cast the any object to what you want

Comment: This is my first app, I do not know how to use NSDictionary. I know I am taking your time, thanks alot...

Comment: Google is your best friend ;) A NSDictionary is a data type which stores a value to a key. You get the result from [this](http://yazar.io/api/article/feed/1) here you see “total_count”: 0, this means the key “total_count” stores the value: 0. Google a bit to find out how to use it, i’m sure you will be able to do this. If you can’t seem to do it tag me again and i’ll try to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link http://yazar.io/api/newspaper/1 gives a 404 error, so obviously you will get a nil returned from the request.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the baseURL in the request

```
 static func articleForSection(section: String, page: Int, response: (JSON) -> ()){

        let urlString = baseURL + ResourcePath.Articles.description
        println(urlString)
        let parameters = [
            "page": toString(page)
        ]
        println(parameters)

        Alamofire.request(.GET, baseURL, parameters: parameters).responseJSON{(_, _, data, _) -> Void in
            let articles = JSON(data ?? [])
            response(articles)
        }
    }
```

change the baseURL to urlString like this

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters).responseJSON{(_, _, data, _) -> Void in
        let articles = JSON(data ?? [])
        response(articles)
    }
```